# Select the only child having the class using CSS & SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm creating a border using SASS for the rows in the '`tbody`' element, but I'm unable to remove it in a case.

For example,

In the 1st '`tbody`' element, `tbody` has 2 children with the class `compDetails-row`.
I'm creating a border there.

However, in the 2nd `tbody` element, as you can see, there's only 1 child with the class `compDetails-row`, I don't want the border to be applied.
Hence, I'm trying to use `only-of-type` selector, but it doesn't seem to work.

How do I fix it?

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .compDetails-row {
      position: relative;
      &:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        border-left: 1px solid grey;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20%;
      }
      &.compDetails-row:only-of-type {
        &:before {
          border: none;
        }
      }
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <tbody>
      <tr class="compDetails-row">
        <td>Row1 Column1</td>
        <td>Row1 Column2</td>
        <td>Row1 Column3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="compDetails-row">
        <td>Row2 Column1</td>
        <td>Row2 Column2</td>
        <td>Row2 Column3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>View Details</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="compDetails-row">
        <td>Row1 Column1</td>
        <td>Row1 Column2</td>
        <td>Row1 Column3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>View Details</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: `:only-of-type` as the name says doesn't care about class. It's 100% about type.

Comment: Do the answer need to be in SASS?

Comment: Not necessarily, I can try and update in SASS later. You can respond to it in css.

Comment: Add a second class to the one you dont want the border on. Then just give the class of border: none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `:first-of-type` literally only checks the tag name (in this case, `tr`) and currently there's no `:first-of-class` pseudo-class. Ideally, you'd be able to modify the table markup at runtime if there's more than one `.compDetails-row`, if not - your best bet is some JavaScript.

You have access to the CSS/SASS, do you not have access to the JavaScript? This question is tagged for CSS only, but as I mentioned it's not really feasible without changing your markup.

Provided you're able to access the JavaScript files, or add a JavaScript tag to the footer of the website, here's a simple pure/vanilla JavaScript way to do it that adds a class `multiple` to the `.compDetails-row` if there's more than one in the same `tbody`.

```js
// Grab all the `<tbody>` elements in the document as an array
var tbodies = document.querySelectorAll('tbody');

// Loop through the `<tbody>`'s we grabbed
for( i = 0; i < tbodies.length; i++ ){

  // Grab all the `.compDetails-row` elements that exist in the current <tbody>
  rows = tbodies[i].querySelectorAll('.compDetails-row');
  
  // If there's more than one `.compDetails-row`
  if( rows.length > 1 ){
  
    // Loop through the `.compDetails-row` elements
    rows.forEach(function(item){
    
      // Add the `multiple` class to them
      item.classList.add('multiple');
      
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.compDetails-row {
  position: relative;
}

.compDetails-row.multiple:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="compDetails-row">
      <td>Row1 Column1</td>
      <td>Row1 Column2</td>
      <td>Row1 Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="compDetails-row">
      <td>Row2 Column1</td>
      <td>Row2 Column2</td>
      <td>Row2 Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>View Details</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="compDetails-row">
      <td>Row1 Column1</td>
      <td>Row1 Column2</td>
      <td>Row1 Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>View Details</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can't we achieve this only using CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not without editing the HTML somehow. CSS doesn't have the ability to do a `:first-of-class`, as nice as it would be. `:first-of-type` is the closest you can get for now, but that doesn't work because you have multiple `<tr>`s. If your first `<tbody>` always has multiple, and the second doesn't - modifying @Swellar's answer would work, but it doesn't care about the children, it would always style the first `tbody`'s rows and skip the others'.

Comment: Your best (and really, only) bet is to add classes to the `.compDetails-row` at runtime or client-side with a little JS

Answer (score 0):

Using [the `:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), [which is currently a working draft and behind a flag in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/css-has), this is achievable with CSS only.

```
tbody:not(:has(.compDetails-row ~ .compDetails-row)) .compDetails-row::before {
  border: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67mo5bdj/)

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume it has a table as a parent, so you can use the pseudo-selectors `first-of-type`, or `first-child` if the table has no `<thead>`

```css
table tbody:first-of-type .compDetails-row td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="compDetails-row">
      <td>Row1 Column1</td>
      <td>Row1 Column2</td>
      <td>Row1 Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="compDetails-row">
      <td>Row2 Column1</td>
      <td>Row2 Column2</td>
      <td>Row2 Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>View Details</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="compDetails-row">
      <td>Row1 Column1</td>
      <td>Row1 Column2</td>
      <td>Row1 Column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>View Details</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think the two `<tbody>`s are just there as an example. This has nothing to do with how many rows have the class.